# Is there a way to get first item from Zend collection without foreach statement

Tags: php, zend-framework, collections

When getting a form item out of a fieldset class I use the code below and it works. The question is: is it possible to get the $item var without the foreach statement? Something like this is what I would like: $collection->{1}->get('event_timeblock_label);

```
$collection = $this->form->get('timeblocks');

foreach($collection as $item) {}
echo $this->formLabel($item->get('event_timeblock_label'));
```